# Bitnami Magento stack on Google Cloud: offering stopped

Tags: google-cloud-platform, magento, bitnami

at the end of August, I got a message from Google saying Bitnami has retracted the Magento stack from Google Cloud. The message states:

> You can continue using Magento packaged by Bitnami until March 1st, 2023 and Bitnami will continue to offer you support during this time.

I have 3 servers (2 of them are a clone of the first one, via restoring a backuo). Does this mean I can no longer boot/run the VM after March 1st? I have made serious customization to this server so it is not ideal to simply re-create them. Is there a workaround to keep them running?

I have looked at the licenses on these VM's (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/licenses/view-append) and I can see a license for Bitnami. I am not sure if this is the reason it will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

This message is related to the removal of the Bitnami Magento 2 instance from the Google Cloud Console Marketplace, meaning it is no longer available for installations of new instances. This does not impact your currently running servers and will not stop them from running.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).